# Expand chaining hashtable. Errors on code.[UPDATED-New question]

Tags: c, hashtable, expand, chaining

Expanding a hashtable with linked lists there are some errors and warnings. I wanna make sure that the following code is right (expand function) and find out what happens that raise these warnings/errors

EDIT:Thanks to @**nos** who noticed that my prototype was missing the warnings+errors I refered to gone. Unfortunately now there is this one: *" In function `expand': undefined reference to`add' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status*

EDIT2: I noticed that add function returns back a List* which on expand function there is none variable to "get" it. I put a value there...but error remains :/

EDIT3: Segmentation Fault :( Running with gdb: *** glibc detected**   corrupted double-linked list: 0x0804c6b0 ** CORRECTED. NEW ADD FUNCTION ADDED.

**EDIT**: Segmentation Fault on strcmp on lookup function. Running with gdb:

> (gdb) bt full
>
> ## 0  0x080487b9 in lookup (hashtable=0x804b008, hashval=27,
>
> ```
> number=0xbffff3f2 "6900101001") at pro.c:80
>     list = 0xffffffff
> ```
>
> ## 1  0x0804883b in add (hashtable=0x804b008,
>
> ```
> number=0xbffff3f2 "6900101001", name=0x804b6e0 "Irgaedggfs",
> ```
>
> time=6943)
>       at pro.c:96
>           new_elem = 0xffffffff
>           hashval = 27
>
> ## 2  0x08048bc1 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff4b4) at pro.c:234
>
> ```
>     number = "6900101001"
>     name = 0x804b6e0 "Irgaedggfs"
>     time = 6943
> ```

```
typedef struct 
{
     int length;        
     struct  List *head;    
} HashTable;

  //resolving collisions using linked lists - chaining
typedef struct 
{
     char *number;
     char *name;
     int time;
     struct List *next;
}List;



HashTable* expand( HashTable* h )
{    
          HashTable* new;
          int n;
          List *node,*next;
          PrimesIndex++;
          int new_size= primes[PrimesIndex];        /* double the size,odd length */

          if (!(new=malloc((sizeof( List*))*new_size))) return NULL;

          for(n=0; n< h->length; ++n) {
                for(node=h[n].head; node; node=next) {
                      add (new, node->number, node->name,node->time);
                      next=node->next;
                      free(node);
                }
          }
          free(h);
          return new;
}


int add ( HashTable* hashtable,char number[10],char* name,int time)
{
     List *new_elem;
    int hashval=hash (hashtable,number);

    new_elem=hashtable[hashval].head;
    if(hashtable[hashval].length>0) 
    {                   
          if ((lookup (hashtable,hashval,number))!=NULL) {return 0;}    
    }

    if (!(new_elem=malloc(sizeof(struct  List)))){ return -1;}

    //insert values for the new elem
    new_elem->number=strdup(number);    
    new_elem->name=strdup(name);
    new_elem->time=time;

    hashtable[hashval].head=new_elem;
    new_elem->next=NULL;
    hashtable[hashval].length++;

    /* rehash existing entries if necessary */
    if( TableSize(hashtable)>= 2*size]) 
    {    
         hashtable = expand(hashtable);
         if (hashtable ==NULL){
           return 0;
         }

    }
    return 1;
}



List *lookup ( HashTable *h ,int hashval,char number[10])
{
    List *list=h[hashval].head;
    for(list; list!=NULL; list=list->next){
            if (strcmp(number,list->number)==0)  //**SEGMENTATION**!!!!
                return list;

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare functions before you call them. Otherwise C will, among other things, assume your `expand` function returns an int.

Simply, place a [prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) like this one at the top of your file, after your struct declarations, before your function definitions.

```
 HashTable* expand( HashTable* h ,char number[10],char* name,int time);
```

Comment: oh!yeah!i've placed all the prototypes except this one! pf! thank you nos! EDIT: hm :/ now there is this one: " In function `expand': undefined reference to `add' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: So where's the add function ?

Comment: So, is all this in one file ? Several files ?

Comment: @nos. If you want take a look at the once again updated post.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

declare the function "add" before you define "expand", in which you use "add".

List* add ( HashTable* hashtable,char number[10],char* name,int time);

define expand here..

define add here...

Comment: I found my error SetTimer,but still cant find how to solve it. Problem is at line: add (&new, node->number, node->name,node->time);
the add function returns a pointer that on expand function none variable gets it. My query now is what variable to put there. If i put the *head every new addition will go to the head and it will provoke segmentation. How can i solve that plainly???

Comment: In terms of syntax, you do NOT have to "receive" a function's return value. Plus, according to the semantics of "expand", I don't think you need the return value of "add". In Edit2, you mentioned there is still some error; Could you provide the error details?

Comment: pls wait a bit. i will update the post with the code i have now.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know how to change lines in the computer; so I have to post an new answer rather than follow your comment. sorry)

Pls try:

int add ( HashTable** phashtable,char number[10],char* name,int time){

```
...

if(hashTableSize( *phashtable)== 2*(primes[PrimesIndex])){ 
     *phashtable = expand( *phashtable);
}
```

}

you may need to modify "add" and the invoke of "add" accordingly.

I'm not sure whether this would help. At least this is one of the bugs.

The bug is that if Hashtable is expanded in an add call, after the add call returns, the value of the variable "hashtable" won't change.

Comment: Ok Thanks. if you can wait please a bit more :) EDIT: pls can u check my add function? I put on comments the calling of expand and on the running time of the file it raised "ABORT" ....corrupt double linked list. :/

Comment: @SetTimer.Pls check post. Do you see any mistake on this: if (strcmp(number,list->number)==0) It flags a segmentation on my lookup function.It cant be null as i prevented of it saying to start search only if list's length>0